# Using the correct image path in HTML

Tags: html, image, vue.js, path

I am having some trouble finding the correct image path to show my image.
I have tried ../src/assets/img/notification-icon.png

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir1gn.png)
[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1To8e.png)
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing us the directory of the file which contains the HTML. I am assuming it is under `src/views`.

Using `..` in a path tells the compiler to look one level up the directory tree.

If your file is in `src/views` that means `src/views/..` evaluates to `src/`. Then, you tell it to look under the `src/assets` folder and the path becomes `src/src/assets`.

Did you see the double `src`?

Your relative path should be changed to `../assets/img/notification-icon.png`.

Using relative paths can be tedious though. I would recommend absolute paths([assuming you use vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules))

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to add that the code is in the index.html file in the public folder. I assume I will have to use relative path since it's an html file?

Comment: @Distance I think webpack processes the `public` folder so you can use absolute paths but you shouldn't be coding your app in the `public` directory. I recommend you read the [official Vue.js guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) - it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Im using the index.html in the public folder for the navbar and footer to be displayed on all pages. Is that wrong? Should I be using the app.vue for that?
I still have views that change.

Comment: @Distance Yes - you should be creating a SFC for the navbar and another one for the footer. Then include them on your App.vue. Vue is smart enough to not re-render elements when the DOM is changed. I would still recommend reading that guide I linked to. Please also consider accepting my answer if it helped you.